# https returns 404 while http works fine

Tags: http, iis, https

I'm trying to configure HTTPS for my application and it's returning "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.", but the resource actually exists.

I've done several tests regarding this problem and here's a list:

- Access via HTTP works perfectly.
- I created a simple HTML file to try to access via HTTPS (https://example.com/myfile.html) and it also worked (which leads to the understanding that the problem is in something in my application).
- Setting binding security mode to "Transport" in WebConfig file.
- Port 443 for HTTPS is fine

PS.: When I try to access the site by HTTPS, by a route and resource that REALLY exists (for example "https://example.com/login.aspx") it returns 404 and recognizes the site as not secure (or i.e. it doesn't recognize the certificate in the route, maybe because it redirects me to http). But, if I try to access a resource that DOES NOT exist, like "https://example.com/Testlogin.aspx", it returns 404 but with a different message (comparisons attached) and recognizes the site as secure (HTTPS).
[image]

It's a C# webforms application with aspx, and I'm trying to set it up on IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

After many tests and running out of alternatives, I decided to investigate whether there was something in the source code that prevented the application from accessing HTTPS. Behold, I finally found the problem: in the application there was the following method that was redirecting the application to HTTP. I just needed to change the call parameter to true and it worked.

```
public void protocoloSeguro(bool bSeguro)
    {

        string redirectUrl = null;

        if (bSeguro && !Request.IsSecureConnection) redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
        else
            if (!bSeguro && Request.IsSecureConnection) redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("https:", "http:");

        if (redirectUrl != null)
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);

    }
```

Comment: Next time you can enable FRT to learn more about such 404 errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing That should tell you if the 404 errors come from IIS itself, or your ASP.NET pages/controllers, so much easier to identify the culprit.